# Comparing pandas DataFrame to Series

Tags: python, pandas

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285661/working-with-comparing-dataframes-and-series-and-generating-new-dataframes-on-th) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220521/how-to-extract-pandas-series-element-and-compare-it-with-rows-in-dataframes-col) question so far but they didn't really help me with my problem.

The problem is very simple but a little difficult to put to words.

I have a Dataframe which is matrix like:

```
       Stock1 Stock2
Date1   3      4
Date2   1      4
```

For each date, which is my index, I want to compare the values to a single point in a Series.

Be the Series like:

```
      Value
Date1   2
Date2   3
```

I want to build the following DataFrame from a comparison like DataFrame > Series

```
       Stock1 Stock2
Date1   True   True
Date2   False  True
```

So for `Date1` both values are greater than 2, and for `Date2` only `Stock2` is greater than 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and pass `axis=0` to compare row-wise against a Series:

```
In [126]:
df.gt(s, axis=0)

Out[126]:
      Stock1 Stock2
index              
Date1   True   True
Date2  False   True
```